# Spring Amqp : Purpose of getRequiredQueueNames method

Tags: java, spring, amqp, spring-amqp

What is the **real** purpose of the [protected String[] AbstractMessageListenerContainer #getRequiredQueueNames()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/1.6.x/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java#L172-L174) method.

Is it for customizing `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` queue names resolution when overloaded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is obsolete since version 1.7 ([AMQP-672](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-672)) and can be removed (it will be in 2.0).

Before version 1.7, the container would not start if no queues were defined. You can now start the container with no queues; you can add them later.